# Printing out the names of implicitly linked dll's from .idata section in a portable executable

Tags: windows, executable, exe, portable-executable

I am trying to write a code which is supposed to print out the names of all the imported dll's in the exe by using the 'name' field of the IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structure in the .idata section of the exe, but the program seems to be getting stuck in an infinite loop. Can someone please tell me how to get the names printed out correctly...

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<Windows.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<WinNT.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE *fp; 
        int i;

        if((fp = fopen("c:\\Linked List.exe","rb"))==NULL)
            std::cout<<"unable to open";


        IMAGE_DOS_HEADER imdh;
        fread(&imdh,sizeof(imdh),1,fp);
        fseek(fp,imdh.e_lfanew,0);

        IMAGE_NT_HEADERS imnth;
        fread(&imnth,sizeof(imnth),1,fp);

        IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *pimsh;
        pimsh = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *)malloc(sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) * imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

        long t;

        fread(pimsh,sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER),imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections,fp);

        for(i=0;i<imnth.FileHeader.NumberOfSections;i++)
        {
            if(!strcmp((char *)pimsh->Name,".idata"))
                t = pimsh->PointerToRawData;
            pimsh++;
        }

        fseek(fp,t,0);

        IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR iid;
        char c;

        while(1)
        {
            fread(&iid,sizeof(iid),1,fp);

            if(iid.Characteristics == NULL)
                break;

            t = ftell(fp);

            fseek(fp,(long)iid.Name,0);

            while(c=fgetc(fp))
                printf("%c",c);
            printf("\n");

            fseek(fp,t,0);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems.

- You can't assume the import section is called ".idata".  You should locate the imports using `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT]`.
- Most offsets within a PE file are Relative Virtual Addresses (RVAs), not file offsets.  To convert an RVA to an offset you need to determine which section the virtual address is in, then calculate an offset based on where the section is in the file.  Specifically, the `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR.Name` field contains an RVA, not a file offset.
- Your code will be much simpler (and quicker) if you use a memory-mapped file rather than file I/O.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) explains RVAs, the data directory, etc.  It also includes `pedump`, an application with full source code for dumping PE files, which is a useful reference.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx
This article says that "The .idata section (or import table) begins with an array of IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs.", if you scroll down to the "PE File Imports" section, second paragraph.

Comment: @user1232138: That article also notes that the Borland linker doesn't  use standard section names.

Comment: concerning the section names: they do not even have to have a name! While developing my own PE analysis tool (PeStudio) I had situations where some PE binaries did have section names begining with non-printable characters, or having code section named ".idata", etc... There is NO fixed rule for section names! The only rule is: the place reserved for their names consist of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by mox is right on all points, however I would also like to add another solution - load the file as an image to read the data.
This is achieved very simply using [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with just one line of code.

```
Base = LoadLibraryEx("c:\Linked List.exe", 0, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
```

This load and maps your executable as an image, so no need for opening/reading/mapping or converting rva to raw offsets.

With the *DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES* flag the image is uninitialized, so all import data is untouched, and entrypoint code is not executed.  The executable is just mapped into memory.

You can simply use *Base + Rva* to find imported dll name - or any other kind of PE information.
Free the executable image after use with *FreeLibrary(Base)*

Comment: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx: "...Do not use this value; it is provided only for backward compatibility. If you are planning to access only data or resources in the DLL, use LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE or both. Otherwise, load the library as a DLL or executable module using the LoadLibrary function."

Comment: This is much simpler but it limits you to either 32-bit or 64-bit DLLs (depending on the flavour of your process).

Comment: @mox: Yes, the DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES works on all systems, as it's backwards compatible, but the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE and LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE flags are not supported until Vista.