# Printing out the name of the first entry in the imports table of a PE file

Tags: windows, executable, exe, portable-executable

I am trying to print out the name of the first entry (which I suppose is user32.dll) in the imports table of a PE file, but the program terminates unexpectedly saying "cannot read memory", can someone please explain me why??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<WinNT.h>


int main()
{


HANDLE  hFile,hFileMapping;
LPVOID lpFileBase;
LPVOID lp;

if((hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("c:\\linked list.exe"),GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    std::cout<<"unable to open";

if((hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL)) == 0)
{
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    std::cout<<"unable to open for mapping";
}

if((lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0))== 0)
{
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    std::cout<<"couldn't map view of file";
}

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pimdh;
pimdh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpFileBase;

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pimnth;
pimnth = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((char *)pimdh + pimdh->e_lfanew);

PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pimsh;
pimsh = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(pimnth + 1);

int i;
for(i = 0; i<pimnth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
{
    if(!strcmp((char *)pimsh->Name,".idata"))
    {
        char *p;

        PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pimid;
        pimid = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(pimnth->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress + (char *)lpFileBase);
        p = (char *)((char *)lpFileBase + pimid->Name);
        printf("%s",p);
    };

    pimsh++;
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

[You asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656147/printing-out-the-names-of-implicitly-linked-dlls-from-idata-section-in-a-porta/) a couple of days ago and looking at your code you've read two-thirds of my answer.

The other third says that `pimid->Name` is not a file offset, it's a Relative Virtual Address (or RVA), which you need to convert to a file offset.  That's why you're getting an error.  To understand RVAs [read the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx).  For sample code to do the conversion have a look at `pedump`, which is referenced in the article.