# Is there a way to programatically check dependencies of an EXE?

Tags: winapi, language-agnostic

I've got a certain project that I build and distribute to users.  I have two build configurations, Debug and Release.  Debug, obviously, is for my use in debugging, but there's an additional wrinkle: the Debug configuration uses a special debugging memory manager, with a dependency on an external DLL.

There's been a few times when I've accidentally built and distributed an installer package with the Debug configuration, and it's then failed to run once installed because the users don't have the special DLL.  I'd like to be able to keep that from happening in the future.

I know I can get the dependencies in a program by running Dependency Walker, but I'm looking for a way to do it programatically.  Specifically, I have a way to run scripts while creating the installer, and I want something I can put in the installer script to check the program and see if it has a dependency on this DLL, and if so, cause the installer-creation process to fail with an error.  I know how to create a simple CLI program that would take two filenames as parameters, and could run a `DependsOn` function and create output based on the result of it, but I don't know what to put in the `DependsOn` function.  Does anyone know how I'd go about writing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command line tool to find Dll dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352951/command-line-tool-to-find-dll-dependencies)

Comment: Why don't you automate your build process. It's trivial to do, saves lots of time, and means you don't make mistakes. Spending time looking at dependencies is solving the wrong problem. The real problem is that you don't have a repeatable build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the PE imports table to find out what DLLs are required at load time.  This is what Dependency Walker does, and also the `dumpbin` tool included with the Microsoft Platform SDK (which is installed by Visual Studio and also available as a separate download).  Some of the debughelp APIs provide access to information from the PE header, but why not invoke the `dumpbin` tool and inspect its output?  Since it's text-based non-interactive it should be pretty straightforward to integrate into your installer build process.  [Dependency Walker also has a capability to run in non-interactive mode with text output](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_command_line_help.htm).

If you do need to retrieve the information without the help of any other tool, the [`ImageDirectoryEntryToDataEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680149.aspx) function is a good place to start.  Also, here's a question that shows how to do it manually (but do use ImageHlp instead, which knows about all the various variants of the PE format):

- [Printing out the names of implicitly linked dll's from .idata section in a portable executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656147/printing-out-the-names-of-implicitly-linked-dlls-from-idata-section-in-a-porta)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: `dumpbin` is actually part of the Windows SDK, so you can get it free without Visual Studio.  Or if I knew what toolchain you do use, I might know if there's a tool bundled with that.

Comment: @Mason: Sorry, not familiar with tools bundled with Delphi.  But it turns out that Dependency Walker has a command-line mode that spits out the import list in CSV or columnar text format.  http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_command_line_help.htm

Comment: That's interesting, but it doesn't look like there's any way to get it to actually output to the console, rather than a file.  That makes things trickier.  But the ImageHlp solution is very useful!

Comment: So what if you are using Delphi. You'll be far better off knowing your way around the MS tools as well.